# php run before ajax is completed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wait

I know PHP runs first but is there a way to get PHP to wait on an ajax request and then run its script? I have a php script here that I want to run but I NEED a variable from my JS file in order for it to run successfully. So was wondering if it's possible?

What I have is a normal request in my JS:

```
var myvar = data; 
$.get('phpscript.php', {myvar: myvar} );
```

And in PHP:

```
$myphp = $_GET['myvar'];
```

But if i echo `$myphp` it returns "undefined", if I alert it however It displays the value; which means the php script is running before it even gets the request from ajax. Any way I could make the PHP wait?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should read something about the difference between server and client-side scripts. It doesn't work this way.

Comment: Why not just post to the php page from the ajax call and grab the variable from there.

Comment: it grabs the variable after the the php already loads

Comment: Php runs server side, automatically, as soon as you load the page, there is no way to make it wait.

Comment: I understand. Well is there anyway way I could get php to recognize the variable before running the script?

Comment: If you use jQuery's $.ajax you can do async:false

Comment: mind showing me an example in code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the PHP that requires a variable in its own script and call it from the ajax call, once the ajax call gets a response update the DOM as needed.

PHP runs on server, then javascript runs on client to make the ajax call, then PHP runs on server returning data, then the javascript gets the data and does something with it.

Comment: I completly can't imagine how to do this. Could You make simple excample?
When I use ajax to get result/variable from php script it always run after Javascript. I would like to do php script before Ajax, then javasccript can see this result.
I would like to do php script dynamically and conditionally when user is completing form. I can't do everything in PHP because I don't know what user will enter and I must generate some things asking database.
And I don't want to reload website.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('phpscript.php', {myvar: myvar}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Inside the php file have something like:

```
$myphp = $_GET['myvar']; 

echo $myphp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, no, you can't make PHP wait.  PHP only runs on the server-side, by the time the AJAX request is sent, by definition, the page is already been sent to the client.

You'll probably have to do some refactoring.  If the variable absolutely needs to be used for a PHP function, then you may need to move that logic into 'phpscript.php' or (less optimally) you may need to issue another AJAX request when you get the response from the first.

But my guess is that more commonly, you'll probably just have to figure out how to do what you want with javascript.  If all you want is something equivalent to a PHP echo, you'll want to use Javascript (or JQuery) DOM manipulation for that.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the other option is simply to do all the PHP stuff on the server-side before you send the page at all, instead of AJAX you'd want to do something in PHP like including your other php script and calling methods from it.  But, everything you do on the server-side, the user is sitting there looking at a blank screen waiting for the page to load.  So this isn't an option for anything that's not very quick.

Comment: Actually I want the js variable so I could make a query in my data base and with the results, do something. Any ideas to make that happen? I tried everything to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how my code is set up, I really need that js variable to access some data from my db then run the php script